# How to submit AJAX forms with user clicking enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am submitting a form with AJAX:

```
$("#frmConferenceSettings").on("submit",function(event){
    // disable default click operation
    event.preventDefault();
    // run the AJAX submit
    update_conference_settings();
});
```

This works fine, however the effect is such that only the `submit button` will work to submit the form; hitting `enter` whilst in a form input is disabled by `event.preventDefault()`.

If `event.preventDefault()` is removed the form submits when the user is in an input field and hits `enter`, but the AJAX via `update_conference_settings()` is lost.

How can I allow the form to be submitted by hitting `enter`, whilst preserving the AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to bind a `keypress` event and `trigger()` the handler on your button.
Didn't try it but it should work.

UPDATE replace `bind` with `on`

```
   $(document).on('keypress', function(e){
       if(e.which === 13) { // enter
          $('#button_id').trigger('click');
       }
   });
```

Comment: Good idea. How would I make sure this is only when the use is focused on the form though?

Comment: You can test if element has focus with `if ($("#elem").is(":focus")) {}`

Comment: This works if I replace `$('#button_id').trigger('click');` with `update_conference_settings();`. Not sure why that would be though?

Comment: Although this solution will work, it is kind of a hack.  It would be best to listen for a submit event on the form and handle that event appropriately.  That way you don't have to have a separate event handler just to mimic a click.  IMO this is a little messy.  Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mNhX/ and my answer below.

Comment: Also, this will submit the form if you have a select box open (drop-down list) and you click 'enter' to select the item.  I just did this on another site while buying something and it reminded me of this post.  You could add this immediately inside the listener: `if ($("#some-select").is(":focus")) return;`, but this is getting out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

You could only call `event.preventDefault()` if it's a certain type (i.e. click) event.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the event.preventDefault() and put 'return false' after update_conference_settings().

Edit: this is how this should work:

```
$(function(){
    $("#my-form").submit(function(){

        update_conference_settings(function(){
            //Here you can redirect to new page or do nothing
            //window.location.href = "/submit-page"
            console.log("3) update_conference_settings complete");
        });

        console.log("2) Default form submit cancelled");
        return false;
    });

    function update_conference_settings(callback)
    {
        //Simulate ajax latency
        console.log("1) Init ajax call");
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback();
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

See this in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6mNhX/6/

Comment: That has the same effect as `event.preventDefault()`; the user can't submit the form with a `carriage return`.